# read command line arguments as list in R script

Tags: arrays, r, list, vector, command-line

How do I read command line args in R in the form of a list?

For eg : Rscript myScript.R hello world

myScript.R code:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly =TRUE)
print(typeof(args)) ---> character
print(args[1])      ---> hello
print(args[2])      ---> world
```

If I'm able to access 1st and 2nd element like above, then why the typeof args is character and why not list?

Also, if it's a character how do I read it as a named list whose first element is hello and second element is world.

If args is a character, then I tried splitting it by space to form a list:

```
args <- strsplit(args , " ")
```

But it creates lists of list. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I think I figured it out...

`args` is indeed a `character` vector composed of two elements. So it is perfectly normal that you may access `'hello'` and `'world'` by using `args[1]` and `args[2]`, respectively.

Now, I do not understand why you want it to be a list... But if you really want it to be a list... maybe you should do:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly =TRUE)
print(typeof(args))
print(args[1]) # 'hello'
print(args[2]) # 'world'
args_names <- args # saving 'hello' and 'world' to be the names of the list
args <- as.list(args) # making the list
names(args) <- args_names # naming the list
print(typeof(args)) # showing that it is now a list
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: When you will do: print(typeof(args_[1]))
      print(typeof(args[2])). It will show list. But elements should be character and args should be list

Comment: That's because you're using the wrong indexing way. To obtain the character elements you should use `args[[1]]` or `args[[2]]`, because they are elements of a list. If you use `args[1]` or `args[2]`, the values returned are lists as well. That's the normal behavior of a list. `args` is already a list.